# not able to open new page on button click

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi Developing an Mobile app using Ionic Framework.
I know its very basic question but i m new to this.
In the `Index.html` is having two buttons 1 is for `Login` and other for `SignUp`

[image]

index.html

```
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <ion-pane>
            <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
          <h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
        </div>

                <ion-content paging="true" class="has-header" >
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/Logo.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
                        <img src="img/Team.jpg" width="70%" height="auto" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
                    </div>
                    <div ng-cntroller="loginCtrl">
                        <button id="btnLogin" class="icon icon-right ion-log-in left button button-positive button-block   " style="border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</div>
<div ng-cntroller="signupCtrl">
                        <button id="btnSignUp" class="button button-positive button-block icon icon-right ion-person left" style="border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;">SignUp</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bar  bar-footer bar-calm">
                        <div class="title">Copyright <strong>@</strong></label>
                    </div>

                </ion-content>

            </ion-pane>
```

On login click it open the `Login.html` page similar way click on sign up it open `Signup.html`

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers','starter.routes','starter.services','starter.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(cordova.platformId === 'ios' && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

routes.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', [])

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouteProvider){
    $stateProvider

    .state('text', {
        url: '/page1',
        templateUrl: 'templates/text.html',
        controller: 'textCtrl'
    });

    .state('login', {
        url: '/page2',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    });

     .state('signUp', {
         url: '/page3',
         templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
         controller: 'signupCtrl'
     });

    .state('chats', {
        url: '/page4',
        templateUrl: 'templates/chats.html',
        controller: 'chatsCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/page1')
});
```

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter')
app.controller('textCtrl',function($scope){

});


app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.login = function(){
alert("Hi")};

});

app.controller('signUpCtrl', function ($scope) {

});

app.controller('chatsCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

login.html

```
<ion-view title="Login" id="page2" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <form id="login-form1" class="list ">
            <ion-list id="login-list1" class=" ">
                <label class="item item-input " id="login-input1">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input " id="login-input2">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
            <a ui-sref="chats" id="login-button3" style="border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;" class=" button button-calm  button-block ">Log in</a>
            <a ui-sref="signup" id="login-button4" class=" button button-positive  button-block button-clear ">Or create an account</a>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Create fiddle instead of pasting all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this link will help to solve my issue

[http://www.joshmorony.com/user-authentication-with-ionic-and-parse-part-1-email-login/](http://Help%20me%20alot)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what the login button should do. Two ways to go

Either do

```
<button id="btnLogin" ui-sref="login">Login</button>
```

or do this on ng-click of the button like

```
$scope.login = function(){
 $state.go('login');
};
```

Make sure $state is injected into your controller.

Comment: ok I just noticed that in your html where you have the login button, you need to use ng-controller='LoginCtrl' on the parent element or the page. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes I tried this also I have updaed the code. I add ng-controller to Login Button in a div tag

Comment: from where I injected $state in controller